# How to open new window using Vim Tsuquyomi plugin and :TsuDefinition command?

Tags: vim

I use `Vim` and `Tsuquyomi` Plugin. Also, I use `:TsuDefinition` command navigate to function/type definition. This command replaces the current window with the new file. Is it possible using this plugin open definition on a new window?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `Tsuquyomi` Doc:

`:TsuquyomiSplitDefinition` - Split current window in two. Navigate to the location where
        the symbol is defined.